# Open form and set mdi parent form (Form1 is a 'type' but is used like a variable)

Tags: c#, .net

```
Form1 (mdiContainer)
   |
   ->Form2 (mdiChild, opened from Form1)
      |
      ->Form3
```

How to open form3 from mdiChild form2 and set Form1 as mdiParent ?

If I try:

```
Form3 frm = new Form3(this);
frm.MdiParent = Form1;
frm.Show();
```

I get error:

```
'Form1' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'
```

Comment: You should name your forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this...

```
Form3 frm = new Form3(this);
frm.MdiParent = this.MdiParent;
frm.Show();
```

I Assume that Form3 is opening from Form2 and Form2's MDI Parent is Form1.

Answer (score 0):

As the error clearly states, you need to use an *instance* of the `Form1` class.

Your code needs to somehow get the correct instance of `Form1`.
You might be able to get that from `this.MdiParent`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Form3 frm = new Form3(this);
frm.MdiParent = this.Parent;
frm.Show();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
frmAbout ObjAbout = new frmAbout();
ObjAbout.MdiParent = **frmMDImain.ActiveForm**;
ObjAbout.Show();
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, it is better to explain the essential parts of the answer and possibly what was the problem with OPs code.